# how to install Ubuntu on Asus Transformer TF101

Tags: tablet

I am Linux layman. Just entry level and learning.
I have an Asus Transformer TF 101 that would like to run Ubuntu or other suitable distro.
Don't know how to do it. I need help on indicating me simple, clear, understandable tutorials or documentation on how to do this. All that I found so far is to much abstruse, or improper time consuming for me on this stage. I really want to learn by understanding and doing  not by doing without understanding. Thank you very much. Gerula

Answer (score -1):

First create Live usb by following these steps here : 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Remember : Format your USB 
Make sure its compatible

Then the installation part :
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop
This will wipe your hard disk and windows
You may have to purchase windows again if you dont want ubuntu after installing

If you want both windows and ubuntu then follow these : 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony

Comment: Asus Transformer TF 101 is an Android tablet.  When I migrated from Windows to Ubuntu on my Dell laptop I followed the steps mentioned in your answer.  Now I intend to transform my Asus tablet ( it has keyboard dock) which now runs under Adroid, in  a notebook  running Debian or Ubuntu. And that is what I don't know to do it.  Thank you.